# Microsoft Teams Powershell module questions

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have two weird problems with the MS Teams Powershell module. I am using the powershell module to create a team automatically if a user requests it through our self service portal.

1. When creating a team with a service account (through the New-Team cmdlet) and add a second user using the Add-TeamUser -Role owner cmdlet, it happens sometimes that the user gets added as a member instead of an owner. Then, after a while (sometimes even a full day!) the owner permissions are added.
2. When creating a team with a service account which has the roles Teams Service Administrator AND Sharepoint Administrator, I get the following error:
   Access token validation failure. Invalid audience
   So, the cmdlet `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` works, but then the snippet `New-Team` or even `Get-Team` gives this error. I even tried adding GLOBAL ADMINISTRATOR, but that doesnt solve it as well. I have another user which is also global admin, and that works. What do I need to set up with this user to get it to work?
   EDIT1: I added a license (E5) to this user, because the other account did have it. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

When we create new teams through powershell it takes some time to replication. max replication time is 24hours.

check user is restrict to create teams or not.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/how-do-i-control-who-can-make-teams/m-p/26747

compare both working and not working account. and provide required permissions to the account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/using-admin-roles